# Add a drop-down list to a pager

Tags: 7, paging

I want to add drop-down list that allows users to select which page they want to visit.

How can I accomplish this?
What code should I use?

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand what is being asked here. Please expand the question, and make clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i am sorry.,i have explainned the question clear. namly, i want to add a specific location function to the page.which using an input textbox. the user enters the number that he wants to vist to the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the whole site pager with a drop-down list, you should write a custom module (see 1 and 2). If you want to show it only for some pages, you just invoke the module (see 2):
1. Declare this in the template.php of your theme (replace `YOURTHEMENAME` and `YOURMODULENAME` with the appropriate theme/module name):

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.

  return drupal_get_form('YOURMODULENAME_pagerform', $_GET['q'], $pager_max, $pager_current);
}
```

2. Create a custom module, adding the following code to the YOURMODULENAME.module file:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_pagerform(&$form_state, $path, $pager_max, $pager_current = 0) {
  $form = array();  
  $pagers = array();

  for ($i=0;$i<$pager_max;$i++) {
    $pagers[$i] = $i+1;
  }

  $form['pager'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Current page'),
    '#options' => $pagers,
    '#default_value' => $pager_current,
    '#attributes' => array('onchange' => 'this.form.submit();'),
  );
  $form['path'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $path,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Submit'), 
    '#attributes' => array('style' => 'display: none;') 
  );

  return $form;
}

function YOURMODULENAME_pagerform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_goto($form_state['values']['path'], 'page='.$form_state['values']['pager']);
}
```

p.s. The code was quickly written in browser without any debugging, so may be some errors happen, but it's should give "idea".

Comment: If you want to show it only for some pages, you just invoke the module , i don't know how to do this. thank you.

Comment: i don't want to replace the whole site pager with a drop-down list,i only want to add a  drop-down list after the pager. how to alter the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Jump module](http://drupal.org/project/jump). It's documentation is [here](http://drupal.org/node/276667).